# Recurrence relation for $I_n=\int (\sin x+\cos x)^n \,\Bbb dx$

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations, reduction-formula

We can obtain a recurrence relation for
$$I_n=\int (\sin x+\cos x)^n \,\Bbb dx$$
as $$nI_n= (\sin x+ \cos x)^{n-1} (\sin x- \cos x)+2(n-1)I_{n-2} \tag{$\ast$}$$
By writing $I_n=2^{n/2}J_n$, where $J_n=\int \sin^n (x+a) \,\Bbb dx=\int \sin ^n t \,\Bbb dt$
\begin{align} J_n&=\int \sin ^{n-2} t (1-\cos^2t) \,\Bbb dt \\ &=J_{n-2}-\int \cos t ~ \sin^{n-2}t ~\cos t \,\Bbb dt \end{align}
Integration by parts yields
$$J_n=J_{n-2}-\cos t~ \frac{\sin^{n-1} t}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}J_n\implies nJ_n=(n-1)J_n-\cos t ~\sin^{n-1} t.$$
The question is: How else can one prove/get $(\ast)$?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $1/n$ in your recurrence.

Comment: Oh! yes, thanks, corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write
$$I_n = \int (\sin x + \cos x)^n \,dx = \int (\sin x + \cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x - \cos x)'\,dx$$
and integrate by parts to get
$$I_n = (\sin x + \cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x - \cos x) + (n-1)\int(1-2\sin x \cos x)(\sin x + \cos x)^{n-2}\,dx$$
Now write
$$1-2\sin x \cos x = 2 - (\sin x + \cos x)^2$$
and substitute that into the last expression to get
$$n I_n = (\sin x + \cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x - \cos x) +2(n-1)I_{n-2}$$

Answer (score -3):

Multiplying both sides of the identity

$$(\sin x +\cos x)^2=-(\sin x-\cos x)^2+2$$

with $n(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}$ we have

$$n(\sin x +\cos x)^n=
-n(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\sin x-\cos x)^2+2n(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}.$$

Arranging the right hand side we have

$$(nI_n)'=\color{blue}{(-n+1)(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\sin x-\cos x)^2}\color{red}{-(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\sin x-\cos x)^2
+2(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}}+2(n-1)(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}$$

and

$$(nI_n)'=\color{blue}{(n-1)(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-2}(\cos x-\sin x)(\sin x-\cos x)}+\color{red}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\cos x +\sin x)}+(2(n-1)I_{n-2})'$$

and

$$(nI_n)'=(\color{purple}{(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x-\cos x)})'+(2(n-1)I_{n-2})'.$$

Finally integrating we obtain the recurrence relation

$$nI_n=(\sin x+\cos x)^{n-1}(\sin x-\cos x)+2(n-1)I_{n-2}.$$

Comment: Recurrence relations are generally obtained by using integration by parts as stated in previous answers or in the question, do not use differentiation in such cases because that will yield nothing and for finding the final recurrence relation, you will have to integrate which will be  rather more difficult.

Comment: It disproved the formula given.

Comment: Mathematically you may be correct, I have not checked your relation becaause you did not even explain how you got it, but moreover it does not actualy answer OP's question. If you disproved the given formula, kindly show your solution and present the formula you feel to be correct

Comment: I could disprove it before the accepted answer if I had a pen, actually I uploaded my answer before.

Comment: Whenever you get a pen, kindly work on letting OP know how you disproved his answer because right now it is not (atleast for me) clearly understandable how you would proceed using this and how you even got this.

Comment: Why ARE there so many downvotes here? I dont get it.

Comment: I think you should try explaining some of the steps, like using what formula/property and how you simplified stuff because I am kind of a beginner in this so without atleast some explanation of the property used in the steps/simplification, I do not understand this stuff